# Pulling ints from string and inserting to c++ map

Tags: c++, string, loops, dictionary, int

I have several strings formatted something like 234=10, 10=1, etc.

I want to get each line in to a map, so for example 
234=10 should be in a map like map[234] = 10

I have tried traversing the string char by char using a for loop but I'm struggling getting the 2 separate ints before and after the '='

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please provide your code that you've been struggling with, for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to find the position of the `=`:

```
auto posEqual = str.find("=");
```

Then, you have to cut the string, using `substsr`:

```
int key = std::stoi(str.substr(0, pos)); //Takes string from beginning until 'pos'
```

Then almost the same for the other part

```
int value = std::stoi(str.substr(pos + 1)); //Takes string from 'pos' + 1 until end of str
```

Adding them to the map is trivial:

```
map[key] = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use std::strtol which returns where parsing ends (ie. the '=') and skip over it:

```
auto inp = "12354=43";
char* end_inp;
auto key = std::strtol(inp, &end_inp, 10);
//+1 to skip the '=', don't need to know where parsing stopped (nullptr)
auto value = std::strtol(end_inp + 1, nullptr, 10);
```

Note that this does not require the input string `inp` to be converted to a string (and copied to the heap) as required by the stxxx family of functions.